# Select statement is not returning values for distances

Tags: mysql, math, gps, coordinates, haversine

I am trying to calculate and return the distances between some points.

Here is the complete MYSQL statement that I am using. I have tried multiple versions of this formula, and they all have similar results: returning zero result. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
SET @origLat = 37.386337;
SET @origLon = -122.085823;
SET @dist = 20;

SELECT user_id, user_lat, user_lon, 3956 * 2 * 
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((@origLat - abs(user_lat))*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS(@origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(user_lat)*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN((@origLon-(user_lon))*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          AS distance 
FROM myTable
WHERE user_lon BETWEEN (@origLon-@dist/abs(cos(radians(@origLat))*69))  AND (@origLon+@dist/abs(cos(radians(@origLat))*69))  AND 
      user_lat BETWEEN (@origLat-(@dist/69))  AND (@origLat+(@dist/69)) 
      HAVING distance < @dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

Here is what is in my table.

[image]

Running just my SELECT clause shows that Distance is return nil.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified if the distance formula is correct? You can try copying your data to a spreadsheet or some other utility and try building up the formula gradually to see which part is problematic.

Comment: works for me with non-null distances see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62d72/1). perhaps you didnt execute the set variables before running the select ?

Comment: Yeah it's driving me crazy. If i plug in actual values for the variables, it still doesn't execute.